# Hide UISearchBar clear text button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I would like to know how to hide or not display the `UISearchBar` cross that appears in the `textField` fo the `UISearchBar`

I have tried using this

```
filterSearchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
```

However this is an actual cancel button not the small grey cross, so I would like to know if there is an equivalent for the small grey button that shows in the `UISearchBar`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to get the textField of the Search Bar:

```
UITextField *textField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
```

hope this help! =)

Comment: Where do you find the key "_searchField" is it somewhere in documentation?

Comment: You can find it in the run time headers. I.e. https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers.

Comment: This throws an exception on the latest Xcode at least in my tests

Answer (score 11):

There's a better way to do this, and you don't have to use private APIs or traverse subviews to do it, so this solution is App Store safe.

UISearchBar has a built-in API for doing this:

[[UISearchBar setImage:forSearchBarIcon:state]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISearchBar/setImage:forSearchBarIcon:state:)

The SearchBar icon key you want is UISearchBarIconClear, and you want the UIControlStateNormal state. Then give it a clear image for the image, and you're done.

So, it should look like this:

```
[searchBar setImage:clearImage forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: While this technically makes the button invisible, you can still tap it. But +1 for using official APIs.

Comment: anyone found a non-hack solution to prevent interaction to the button?

Answer (score 9):

Based on @Gines answer, here is the Swift version:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    guard let firstSubview = searchBar.subviews.first else { return }

    firstSubview.subviews.forEach {
        ($0 as? UITextField)?.clearButtonMode = .never
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tom thanks for the edit. Looks perfect. Is this a correct approach?

Comment: I actually think Soto_iGhost's approach is best to solve this particular problem. But when I saw your code I couldn't help myself to edit it ☺️ There are of course many approaches to write this same piece of logic, but I like this one the best.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4**

Adding to Alexander's answer and block user interaction on clear button:

**To hide button:**

```
searchBar.setImage(UIImage(), for: .clear, state: .normal)
```

**To disable user interaction on the clear button, simply subclass UISearchBar**

```
class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar {

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let view = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        if view is UIButton {
            return view?.superview // this will pass-through all touches that would've been sent to the button
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution for swift 4+, I have been using above methods which takes "_searchField" as key. but application is crashing at iOS 13.2.2. This solution has fixed my problem both for lower iOS versions and latest one.

Answer (score 8):

## Swift 5

**Tested on iOS 13**

One liner working for me:

```
searchBar.searchTextField.clearButtonMode = .never
```

You can also set it to `.whileEditing` to have it displayed when the user is typing and then removed when the search bar loses focus.

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3, based on @Alexsander answer:

```
searchBar.setImage(UIImage(), for: .clear, state: .normal)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the clear text button for all UISearchBar instances:

```
[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]].clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
```

Comment: THIS is the only valid non-hackish answer. Good job!

Comment: This answer looks good - can we still set it for a search bar of a particular view-controller class? I've searchbar at multiple places and need to update this for only one class.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5**

Just add a single line below

```
searchBar.searchTextField.clearButtonMode = .never
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 solution :

```
extension UISearchBar{
    var textField : UITextField{
        return self.value(forKey: "_searchField") as! UITextField
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
searchBar.textField.clearButtonMode = .never
```

Comment: this is crashing

Answer (score 2):

I tried different solutions about this issue, even the one selected in this post, but they didn't work.

This is the way I found to solve this issue:

```
UIView *subview = [[searchBar subviews] firstObject]; //SearchBar only have one subview (UIView)

//There are three sub subviews (UISearchBarBackground, UINavigationButton, UISearchBarTextField)
for (UIView *subsubview in subview.subviews)
{
    //The UISearchBarTextField class is a UITextField. We can't use UISearchBarTextField directly here.
    if ([subsubview isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]])
    {
            [(UITextField *)subsubview setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked!, the key was to search through subviews of first subview of Searchbar. See my answer for swift version

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    UITextField *textField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;

}
```

Comment: some explanation please?

Answer (score 1):

In Case of Swift 2.3 just use :

```
var searchBar = UISearchBar();
searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 00, 20))
for subview: UIView in (searchBar.subviews.first?.subviews)!
        {
            if (subview.isKindOfClass(UITextField) )
            {
                let textFieldObject = (subview as! UITextField)
                textFieldObject.clearButtonMode = .Never;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.3, based on @Alexsander answer:

```
searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "SearchClearIcon"), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Clear, state: UIControlState.Highlighted)
searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "SearchClearIcon"), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Clear, state: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting Soto_iGhost's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21522796/4886069) to Swift 4:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    let textField: UITextField = searchBar.value(forKey: "_searchField") as! UITextField
    textField.clearButtonMode = .never
}
```

If you have an outlet of `UISearchBar` the you can write above code anywhere in your class.

Answer (score 1):

thijsonline's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47656108/1603234) in swift:

```
(UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])).clearButtonMode = .never
```