# Remove clear button in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I want to remove the clear button (gray x) from the UISearchBar. I tried to do it like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19458201), but it doesn't work.

I translated the Objective-C code from the answer and the comment below to following Swift code:

```
for subview in searchBar.subviews {
        configureSearchBarView(subview as UIView)
}

func configureSearchBarView(view: UIView) {
    for subview in view.subviews {
        self.configureSearchBarView(subview as UIView)
    }
    if subview.conformsToProtocol(UITextInputTraits) {
        var clearView = view as UITextField
        clearView.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Never
    }
}
```

Unfortunatly this doesn't remove the clear button.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24441925) suggests to work with `appearanceWhenContainedIn`, but this method doesn't seem to be implemented in Swift.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. It is possible to exchange the clear button with a custom image:

```
UISearchBar.appearance().setImage(UIImage(named: "emptyImg"), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Clear, state: UIControlState.Normal)
UISearchBar.appearance().setImage(UIImage(named: "emptyImg"), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Clear, state: UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

`emptyImg` is an png that contains one white pixel. Found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19438100/1447641)

Answer (score 7):

**Swift**

I found a better way that completely removes the button, using **clearButtonMode = .never**

```
let searchBarStyle = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
searchBarStyle?.clearButtonMode = .never
```

Comment: Why the restoration ID? That doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: Hm, I thought that's how you identified the searchField.

Comment: Nope, that `searchField` is basically a hidden property `var searchField: UITextField` which we are accessing through key-value coding. Since it's hidden (undocumented) property, it can stop working on next iOS minor release.

Answer (score 6):

## Swift 5

**Tested on iOS 13**

As I pointed out in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59662858/11783958), this is the one liner working for me to make it disappear completely:

```
searchBar.searchTextField.clearButtonMode = .never
```

However you may also set it to `.whileEditing` if you only want it displayed when the user is typing and then make it disappear when the search bar loses focus.