# iOS10 How can I hide "x" symbol of the searchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I can display and hide keyboard. There is a problem: when I tap something in the searchBar, there is a X symbol in the left of the searchBar and a cancel button. If I click cancel button first and then click the X symbol, I will got an fatal error: Index out of range.

[image]

So I want to hide the “x” symbol rather than “cancel” button. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: And this is my project https://github.com/MartinSnow/ChinaWeather.git

Comment: Rather handle it than hiding it, the problem is that your code dont handle empty text or something

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522104/hide-uisearchbar-clear-text-button

Comment: It's the "clearButton" (that what you were looking for, and there is already doc/question about it). Now, as suggested by @Tj3n the real issue is that your code doesn't manage some case. I would strongly suggest to fix that first, then hide the clearbutton if you want to.

Answer (score 4):

Get the textfield and hide it.

```
UITextField *textField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
```

or Swift you can alwasy extend the search bar and override it.

```
class NoCancelButtonSearchController: UISearchController {
    let noCancelButtonSearchBar = NoCancelButtonSearchBar()
    override var searchBar: UISearchBar { return noCancelButtonSearchBar }
}

class NoCancelButtonSearchBar: UISearchBar {
    override func setShowsCancelButton(_ showsCancelButton: Bool, animated: Bool) { /* void */ }
}
```

Comment: just because you don't know how to translate obj-c to swift, does not make the answer invalid lol. Just ask how to translate it and I will help.  But since you down voted me without checking on the language help, not cool.

Comment: @Moritz the user never requested a Swift version, but I'm happy to supply one as I can see his code is swift.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5**

hide the x icon within the `UISearchBar`:

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).clearButtonMode = .never
```